# Cakephp 3.1 - How to redirect based on query string values?

Tags: cakephp, redirect, url-routing, cakephp-3.1

We recently updated our site from pure php to cakephp 3 and having trouble redirecting urls that have params to a new url.

For example this redirect works fine

```
$routes->redirect('/webcast.php', '/webcast', ['status' => 302]);
```

But if there's parameters, it doesn't work

```
$routes->redirect('/webcast.php?id=100', '/webcast', ['status' => 302]);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router doesn't support matching on query strings, the URL passed to the router when checking for a matching route won't have any query string values attached anymore.

While it would be possible to workaround this by using a custom routing dispatcher filter, a custom/extended `Router` class, and a custom/extended `RouteCollection` class, this seems like way too much work for something that can easily be defined as for example a rewrite rule on server level.

Apache `mod_rewrite` example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=100$
RewriteRule ^webcast\.php$ /webcast? [L,R=302]
```

And note that [**`301` is usually the preferred redirect method**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).

See also

- **[Apache > HTTP Server > Documentation > Version 2.4 > Apache mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/)**